# making, saving and displaying a bmp

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to make a bitmap and save it  and display it. I can display it but I cannot save it.
I get this runtime error : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'
I am even using using and I still get that error

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        byte[] returndata = new byte[7057600];

            for (int x = 0; x < returndata.Length; )
            {

               returndata[x] = 255;
               returndata[x + 1] = 255;
               returndata[x + 2] = 0;
               returndata[x + 3] = 0;
               x = x + 4;

        }

        using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog())
        { 
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Bitmaps|*.bmp";

            Bitmap temp = null;
            temp = InttoBitmap(returndata);
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {


                string location = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

                temp.Save(location, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                pictureBox1.Image = temp;
            }
        }

    }

    int keepWidth = 3208;
    int keepHeight = 2200;
    public Bitmap InttoBitmap(byte[] array)
    {
        unsafe
        {

            IntPtr pixptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(keepWidth * keepHeight * 4);
            Marshal.Copy(array, 0, pixptr, keepWidth * keepHeight);
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(keepWidth, keepHeight, 2 * keepWidth, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pixptr);

            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Did you try to overwrite a bitmap you read before? Or write to a place without write rights, like c:\  ? Can you display the image in a Picturebox?

Comment: Don't make a bitmap from a pointer. Make a new 32bppARGB bitmap, open its backing contents using BitmapData, and copy your data into it using `Marshal.Copy`.

Comment: Your actual error here is that you are trying to put 32-bit data into a 24-bit image, and that you gave `2 * keepWidth` as stride instead of `4 * keepWidth`, btw.

Comment: Taw, I am using winforms. I am not reading from a bitmap. I am making one in realtime. yes, I can display it so the picture box